# cbind multiple, individual columns in a single data frame using column numbers

Tags: r

I have a single data frame of 100 columns and 25 rows. I would like to cbind different groupings of columns (sometimes as many as 30 columns) in several new data frames without having to type out each column name every time.
*Some columns that i want fall individually e.g. 6 and 72 and some do lie next to each other e.g. columns 23, 24, 25, 26 (23:26).*

Usually i would use:

```
z <- cbind(visco$fish, visco$bird)
```

for example, but i have too many columns and need to create too many new data frames to be typing the name of every column that i need every time. Generally i do not attach my data.

I would like to use column numbers, something like:

```
z <- cbind(6 , 72 , 23:26, data=visco)
```

and also retain the original column names, not the automatically generated V1, V2. I have tried adding deparse.level=2 but my column names then become "visco$fish" rather than the original "fish"

I feel there should be a simple answer to this, but so far i have failed to find anything that works as i would like.

Comment: why not just use column indexing? `z <- visco[, c(6,72)]`

Comment: Have you used `dplyr` before? You can use the `select` function to select the variables/columns you want eg `new_df <- iris %>% select(Sepal.Length, Species)`

Comment: z <- visco[, c(6,72)]   a simple and effective solution, thanks.

Comment: I have not used dplyr before, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

```
 df <- data.frame(AA = 11:15, BB = 2:6, CC = 12:16, DD = 3:7, EE = 23:27)
 df
 #   AA BB CC DD EE
 # 1 11  2 12  3 23
 # 2 12  3 13  4 24
 # 3 13  4 14  5 25
 # 4 14  5 15  6 26
 # 5 15  6 16  7 27

 df1 <- data.frame(cbind(df,df,df,df))
 df1
 #   AA BB CC DD EE AA.1 BB.1 CC.1 DD.1 EE.1 AA.2 BB.2 CC.2 DD.2 EE.2 AA.3 BB.3
 # 1 11  2 12  3 23   11    2   12    3   23   11    2   12    3   23   11    2
 # 2 12  3 13  4 24   12    3   13    4   24   12    3   13    4   24   12    3
 # 3 13  4 14  5 25   13    4   14    5   25   13    4   14    5   25   13    4
 # 4 14  5 15  6 26   14    5   15    6   26   14    5   15    6   26   14    5
 # 5 15  6 16  7 27   15    6   16    7   27   15    6   16    7   27   15    6

 # CC.3 DD.3 EE.3
 # 1   12    3   23
 # 2   13    4   24
 # 3   14    5   25
 # 4   15    6   26
 # 5   16    7   27


 Result <- data.frame(cbind(df1[,c(1:5,14:17,20)]))
 Result
 #   AA BB CC DD EE DD.2 EE.2 AA.3 BB.3 EE.3
 # 1 11  2 12  3 23    3   23   11    2   23
 # 2 12  3 13  4 24    4   24   12    3   24
 # 3 13  4 14  5 25    5   25   13    4   25
 # 4 14  5 15  6 26    6   26   14    5   26
 # 5 15  6 16  7 27    7   27   15    6   27
```

Note: The columns with same name are adjusted in their next appearance as `.1` or `.2` by R itself.

Comment: The last bit " data.frame(cbind(df1[,c(1:5,14:17,20)])) " this helped, thanks. The first part wasn't exactly what i was looking for but good to know. Thanks.

Comment: That is just creating data and extra information to understand, so that you will get to know how `Result` came up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do this using the `select` function from `dplyr` - which should be your go to package for this type of data wrangling

```
> library(dplyr)
> df <- head(iris)
> df
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> 
>## select by variable name
>newdf <- df %>% select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width,Species)
> newdf
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5  setosa
2          4.9         3.0  setosa
3          4.7         3.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1  setosa
5          5.0         3.6  setosa
6          5.4         3.9  setosa

>## select by variable indices
> newdf <- df %>% select(1:2,5)
> newdf
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5  setosa
2          4.9         3.0  setosa
3          4.7         3.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1  setosa
5          5.0         3.6  setosa
6          5.4         3.9  setosa
```

However, I'm not sure why you would need to do this? Can you not run your analyses on the original dataframe?

Comment: Yes i can run the anlysis on the original data frame, but for reporting i need much more manageable/easy-to-read examples of the data used to construct certain graphs. Plus i just find it more manageable to work with. Thank you.

Comment: @Rebecca if my answer works then please could you accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as , subsetting a large dataframe into smaller ones. Which could be achieved in different ways. One way is, `data.table` package helps you to retain the column names, and yet subset it by indexing the columns.

if you have your data as `dataframe`, you can just do

```
DT<- data.table(df)
# You still have to define your subsets of columns you need to create

sub_1<-c(2,3)
sub_2<-c(2:5,9)
sub_3<-c(1:2,5:6,10)

DT[ ,sub_2, with = FALSE]
```

Output

```
  bird       cat        dog       rat        car
1: 0.2682538 0.1386834 0.01633384 0.5336649 0.43432878
2: 0.2418727 0.7530654 0.26999873 0.2679446 0.00859734
3: 0.1211858 0.2563736 0.92637523 0.8572615 0.63165705
4: 0.4556401 0.2343427 0.09324584 0.8731174 0.50098461
5: 0.1646126 0.9258622 0.86957980 0.3636781 0.89608415
```

Data

```
require("data.table")
DT <- data.table(matrix(runif(10*10),5,10)) 
colnames(DT) <- c("fish","bird","cat","dog","rat","tiger","insect","boat","car", "cycle")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
z <- visco[c(6,72,23:26)]

Answer (score -1):

In R we have vectors and matrices. You can create your own vectors with the function c.

```
c(1,5,3,4)
```

They are also the output of many functions such as

```
rnorm(10)
```

You can turn vectors into matrices using functions such as `rbind`, `cbind` or `matrix`.

Create the matrix from the vector 1:1000 like this:

```
X = matrix(1:1000,100,10)
```

What is the entry in row 25, column 3 ?

Comment: If you need to ask question to the OP, please use the comment sections instead.